# What's the best way of creating an email verification in Django?

Tags: django-views, email-validation

So, My idea is:

- Create a user
- Verification Code is send in email
- Confirm email and active user

I tried this views, creating the user but not activate it. Then comparing the user code with the generated code.

but it isn't working

```
def createuser(request):
    form = MyUserCreationForm()
    # confirmed = User.is_email_confirmed
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():     

            code = User.objects.make_random_password(length=6,allowed_chars='1234567890')

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.email = user.email.lower()
            user.is_active = False
            
            user.profile.code = code
            user.save()
            login(request,user)
            

        
    
            subject = 'Confirm your email' 
            confirmation_code = code
            message = f'Confirm your email with this code: {confirmation_code}'
            from_email = '...@gmail.com'
            to_email = request.POST['email']
            send_mail(subject,message,from_email,[to_email]).save()
            user.save()
            return redirect('verification')
        
        else:
            messages.error(request,'An error occured during your registration')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)

def verifycode(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        code = request.POST['code']
        
        # Check if the verification code matches
        if request.user.profile.code == code:
            # Mark the user as active
            request.user.is_active = True
            request.user.save()
            # Log in the user
            login(request, request.user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            # Handle incorrect verification code
            return render(request, 'verify.html', {'error': 'Incorrect verification code'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'verify.html')
```

any other (and functional) way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

first of all the from code you provide, save user's profile. Add save to

```
user.profile.save() after user.profile.code = code
```

Email sending, its not needed to be saved, you can remove .save() from

```
    send_mail(subject,message,from_email,[to_email]).save()
```

like

```
    send_mail(subject,message,from_email,[to_email])  # Removed .save()
```

also its better to login after verification, so you can remove login after registration in def createuser.

Other way to do this, you can see this one
https://pypi.org/project/Django-Verify-Email/
there are also examples.

I hope this helps!

Comment: excuse me, this django app Django-Verify-Email is helping me, but an error is confusing me. after clicking the verification email, the error: NoReverseMatch at /verification/user/verify-email/ is returned. Below it: Reverse for '/accounts/login/' not found. '/accounts/login/' is not a valid view function or pattern name. There's no enough docs to explain this error. Did you used sometime this App? can you help me?

Comment: more informations: C:\Users\adrya\LoginPage\venv\Lib\site-packages\verify_email\views.py, line 58, in verify_user_and_activate
                return redirect(to=login_page)
            return render(
                request,
                template_name=success_template,
                context={
                    'msg': success_msg,
                    'status': 'Verification Successful!',
                    'link': reverse(login_page)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ … << the error line here

Comment: for troubleshooting steps you can
- Start by locating the code related to the URL that’s causing the issue (the URL, the view, and any templates involved)
- URL Name: Check for typos in the URL name. If you’ve set an app_name in your app’s urls.py, use the namespace when reversing (e.g., {% url 'myapp:my_url_name' %} or reverse('myapp:my_url_name')).
- URL Patterns: Verify that the URL patterns in your urls.py files are correctly defined.

Comment: Also If your templates are inside a folder within the templates folder, specify the folder name when reversing try:
return redirect(request, 'folder_name:index')
# Or render directly to the desired page:
# return render(request, 'folder_name/index.html', {})